# Route traffic to the Softether server via it's own vpn gateway

Tags: routing, softether, split-tunnel

I want to route traffic to the Softether server via the VPN gateway. It may sound foolish, but for security reasons, some ports on the server have to be accessible only with the server's public IP address.

I've used **"Static routing table to push"** for this goal and I didn't fill in the default gateway section.
This method does the job for Windows clients, but not working on Linux clients. I can find every single route I wrote, except the one to route traffic to the public IP via the VPN gateway. Even adding this route manually does not do the job for me.

This is what I've added to the "Static routing table to push" section:

```
<SERVER's.PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS>/255.255.255.255/192.168.20.1, <SOME.OTHER.NETWORK.RANGE>/255.255.255.248/192.168.20.1
```

This is the Windows client routing tables:

```
Network Destination             Netmask          Gateway       Interface        Metric
          0.0.0.0                0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     192.168.1.18     50
<SOME.OTHER.NETWORK.RANGE>    255.255.255.248    192.168.20.14   192.168.20.13    257
<SERVER's.PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS>  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.1     192.168.1.18     306
<SERVER's.PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS>  255.255.255.255    192.168.20.14   192.168.20.13    257
        192.168.20.0          255.255.255.0      192.168.20.14   192.168.20.13    257
        192.168.20.12         255.255.255.252      On-link       192.168.20.13    257
        192.168.20.13         255.255.255.255      On-link       192.168.20.13    257
        192.168.20.15         255.255.255.255      On-link       192.168.20.13    257
```

And this is the Linux Client routing tables:

```
Destination                      Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0                          192.168.75.2    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens33
<SOME.OTHER.NETWORK.RANGE>       192.168.20.14   255.255.255.248 UG        0 0          0 tun0
<SERVER's.PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS>     192.168.75.2    255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ens33
192.168.20.0                     192.168.20.14   255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.20.14                    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
```

Note that I use the **OpenVPN** to connect, and nothing changes if I use Softether client.

Any tips or advice will be appreciated.